# @Transactional with r2dbc-mysql of dev.miku not working

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-webflux, r2dbc-mysql

I'm creating a GET method for an API with Spring Webflux and r2dbc-mysql of dev.miku. For that, I have this repository and this Service:

```
package com.example.db.repository;

import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository;

import com.example.db.entity.ExampleEntity;

public interface ExampleRepository extends R2dbcRepository<ExampleEntity, Long> {
}

package com.example.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.db.entity.ExampleEntity;
import com.example.db.repository.ExampleRepository;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepository example;

    @Transactional
    public Flux<ExampleEntity> getAll() {
    return this.example.findAll();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx.inventory</groupId>
    <artifactId>inventory</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>inventory</name>
    <description>Project to control inventory</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I run the method and I get this error when I execute my service :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.reactivestreams.Publisher beginTransaction(io.r2dbc.spi.TransactionDefinition)' of interface io.r2dbc.spi.Connection.
    at io.r2dbc.pool.PooledConnection.beginTransaction(PooledConnection.java:105) ~[r2dbc-pool-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.pool.PooledConnection.beginTransaction(PooledConnection.java:44) ~[r2dbc-pool-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.R2dbcTransactionManager.doBegin(R2dbcTransactionManager.java:246) ~[spring-r2dbc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.R2dbcTransactionManager.lambda$doBegin$4(R2dbcTransactionManager.java:214) ~[spring-r2dbc-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.onNext(FluxRetry.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at io.r2dbc.pool.MonoDiscardOnCancel$MonoDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(MonoDiscardOnCancel.java:92) ~[r2dbc-pool-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandleFuseable.java:238) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier$MonoSupplierSubscription.request(MonoSupplier.java:148) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxHandleFuseable.java:259) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreElements.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxHandleFuseable.java:163) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:48) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at io.r2dbc.pool.MonoDiscardOnCancel.subscribe(MonoDiscardOnCancel.java:50) ~[r2dbc-pool-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.deliver(AbstractPool.java:467) ~[reactor-pool-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:421) ~[reactor-pool-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:154) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoTakeLastOne$TakeLastOneSubscriber.onComplete(MonoTakeLastOne.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:466) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowPredicateMain.checkTerminated(FluxWindowPredicate.java:540) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowPredicateMain.drainLoop(FluxWindowPredicate.java:488) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowPredicateMain.drain(FluxWindowPredicate.java:432) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowPredicateMain.onComplete(FluxWindowPredicate.java:312) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandleFuseable.java:238) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.util.DiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onComplete(DiscardOnCancelSubscriber.java:104) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:143) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:537) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:343) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:309) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient$ResponseSink.next(ReactorNettyClient.java:340) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient.lambda$new$0(ReactorNettyClient.java:103) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:294) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:403) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:411) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec.handleDecoded(MessageDuplexCodec.java:187) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec.channelRead(MessageDuplexCodec.java:95) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.2.RELEASE.jar:0.8.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1382) ~[netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1245) ~[netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1294) ~[netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

If I remove @Transaction, the code works fine.

Does someone know how I Can use @Transaction with r2dbc-mysql of dev.miku?

Comment: Looks like you are using incompatible versions. Please show your dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using the last version of SpringBoot(3.0.3) and the last version of r2dbc-mysq (0.8.2.RELEASE)

Comment: Please add your dependencies (pom.xml or build.gradle) to your question, I would also suggest to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.4 which was released recently.

Comment: @M.Deinum added my pom.xml. Thank you! I have tried to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.4  and I get the same results

Comment: If I check the MySQL R2DBC dependency that has been build against the 0.9 API of R2DBC. The current version is 1.0.0 (which is also used in Spring R2DBC afaik), and it appears that the MySQL driver isn't compatible with that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this issue to our attention. After investigating the problem, it appears that the root cause is due to the `dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql` library being out of date and inactive for an extended period. As a result, it does not support the latest Spring Data R2DBC.

To address this issue, I recommend using the `io:asyncer:r2dbc-mysql:1.0.0` library, which is the official successor to `dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql`. This updated library should provide the necessary compatibility with Spring Data R2DBC.

You can find this library on our official GitHub repository at https://github.com/asyncer-io/r2dbc-mysql. As the maintainer of `asyncer-io/r2dbc-mysql`, I am available to assist you with any questions or issues you may encounter while using this library.